# Simple pthread! C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have no idea why this doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void *print_message(){

    cout << "Threading\n";
}



int main() {

    pthread_t t1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &print_message, NULL);
    cout << "Hello";

    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> [Description, Resource, Path, Location, Type] initializing argument 3
>   of 'int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void*
>   (*)(void*), void*)' threading.cpp   threading/src   line 24 C/C++
>   Problem

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should declare the thread main as:

```
void* print_message(void*) // takes one parameter, unnamed if you aren't using it
```

Comment: Thats the idea i don't want to put that as a parameter...the above way works

Comment: This is the correct answer. The original question was misformatted, so he got the error message wrong (missing a couple of asterisks, which were taken as italic markup). I've fixed it now.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you *want*, `pthread_create` takes a pointer to a function that takes `void*` as a parameter and returns `void*`. It's been the defined API for decade(s). :) You aren't forced to use it though.

Comment: ok but now lets say if i want to use the print_message as a function rather than thread how do i do that.. Its going to complain about the pointer

Comment: the answer to ^ == print_message(NULL)

Answer (score 19):

Because the main thread exits.

Put a sleep in the main thread.

```
cout << "Hello";
sleep(1);

return 0;
```

The POSIX standard does not specify what happens when the main thread exits.
But in most implementations this will cause all spawned threads to die.

So in the main thread you should wait for the thread to die before you exit. In this case the simplest solution is just to sleep and give the other thread a chance to execute. In real code you would use pthread_join();

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
#endif
void *print_message(void*)
{
    cout << "Threading\n";
}



int main() 
{
    pthread_t t1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &print_message, NULL);
    cout << "Hello";

    void* result;
    pthread_join(t1,&result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope cause i have pthread_join(t1) at the end before return 0. Plus its giving me build errors and not runtime errors :(

Comment: well not really... cause the print_message takes an argument.. Dont want it to take an argument

Comment: You ninja-fixed the build error but didn't write about it, then went on to talk about another problem he'll have. You got marked down because someone (not me) didn't catch that build fix.

Comment: I had to bump you even though I think you're going to overtake my "lesser" answer lol

Comment: @Martin York, Well the thing is when i look at this http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html the Mutexes Example shows the declaration of void *functionC() and then the functionC being used later in the thread... Thats what i was after

Comment: @Shahmir: But the first example on this page shows how to create a pthread and associated function correctly. From that you can call any other function.

Answer (score 3):

When compiling with G++, remember to put the -lpthread flag :)

Comment: I think that might be the issue but im using eclipse any ideas where to add it

Comment: Just noticed ive already done that. :D otherwise it wont compile the pthread funcs

Answer (score 3):

From the pthread function prototype:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
    void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);
```

The function passed to pthread_create must have a prototype of

```
void* name(void *arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

void* print_message(void*) {

    cout << "Threading\n";
}

int main() {

    pthread_t t1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &print_message, NULL);
    cout << "Hello";

    // Optional.
    void* result;
    pthread_join(t1,&result);
    // :~

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy the answer from Loki?

Answer (score 0):

Linkage. Try this:

`extern "C" void *print_message() {...`

Comment: This is wrong because regardless of name mangling, passing a function pointer will pass the correct address of the function.